# The requested URL /ProjectName/users was not found on this server. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am following the quickstart of laravel and it said `"type /users"` but not working for me.
I have wrote in the browser, `http://DomainServer/ProjectName/users` and it throws:

> The requested URL /ProjectName/users was not found on this server.
>   Laravel

I tried the following,

To enable the apache module `mod_rewrite` and also does not work.

Comment: please paste the lines in your `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Steps for Apache Web Server and Laravel in Linux Environment.

1. Open httpd.conf

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
   # for debian users: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```
2. Make sure the DocumentRoot is pointing to the laravel project's public directory
3. Add the Directory element for that path and Allowoverride All... as follows

   ```
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel/public/"

   <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel/public">
   Allowoverride All
   </Directory>
   ```
4. Open .htaccess from ../laravel/public/ and make sure it has the following

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
   Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
5. Restart httpd services

   ```
   sudo service httpd restart
   ```
6. Now `http://DomainServer/users` will work in your browser.

Comment: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` This doesn't exist on my server... should I just create it by my self and follow the instructions? Please help

Comment: For Mac user please ?

Comment: On Debian the `httpd.conf` file is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`; otherwise these instructions were spot-on!

Comment: is there any solution like this for windows?

Comment: what about nginx server ?

Answer (score 5):

Find httpd.conf and change the `<Directory>` element from

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
Allowoverride None
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
Allowoverride All
</Directory>
```

Then it works after restart the apache without change the `DocumentRoot`.

Answer (score 4):

First find the htaccess file in your Laravel project

next add the following coding in htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

save the htaccess file

and restart the apache server using following code

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

remember htaccess file and index.php file must be available in same folder in your project

Answer (score 3):

the default url have a prefix "index.php" before your page if you try .../public/index.php/your_page it will run, so you need to add the module rewrite if you are using appache to write your url without this prefix

Comment: This 'answer' is what lead me to see that this was my problem. Just to expand on it, if you think you should be able to do something like `http://DomainServer/ProjectName/users`, but that doesn't work, try `http://DomainServer/ProjectName/index.php/users` (or maybe `http://DomainServer/ProjectName/public/index.php/users`). If that works, then you have the problem that the answer, above, fixes!

Answer (score 2):

Try pointing your browser to  `http://DomainServer/ProjectName/public/users` - the 'public' folder is the default 'entry point' for your Laravel app.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache .

Comment: thank you Pankaj,. this should be the first thing to check.

Answer (score 0):

For me i enabled the mod_rewrite and it worked for me well.
Enable mod_rewrite for Apache:
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo a2enmod rewrite

Answer (score 0):

in my case I wanted to get this route as not authenticated user .
RouteServiceProvider has default :

```
/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

which means you need to add that prefix "**api/**" to your url, say:

```
http://yourdomain.com/api/route_url_part
```

Then put route to **api.php** , not **web.php** wich is  auth 'middlwared'

**(optionally for Android emulators)**
if you are trying to do that in, say, android emulator you have to shut down server and start it as:

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

and in java android url instead of localhost put in the ip  retrived from  prompt window's **ipconfig** command.  Say mine was **192.168.0.106**
(**IPv4 Address** one). Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted

Change to

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).