# laravel the requested url was not found on this server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, laravel, laravel-4

I've an Ubuntu 14.04 kernel. I was installing my Laravel application in this server. 
After installing, I tried to set the root directory to public.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

I have only these options in the file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I've changed the Document root to

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/
```

Now when I tried to access my Laravel App, through `123.xxx.xxx.xxx/` it shows the home page and working well. It gets all the GET variable too. Eg: `123.xxx.xxx.xxx?type=wefwef`

But when I go to other links such as `123.xxx.xxx.xxx/login` it gives me an error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /login/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 104.236.234.85 Port 80
```

I have the routes.php working well on localhost. But not on this server. Please help me.

Comment: Does `123.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php/login` work?

Comment: I had the exact same problem and the accepted answer didn't work for me, turns out I had forgotten to enable modrewrite. Some other answers cover all the bases. On Ubuntu you just `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, but my thing is on an Apple MacBook so I had to find and uncomment the modrewrite line in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

This looks like you have to enable `.htaccess` by adding this to your vhost:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you have [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled.

Don't forget to restart apache after making the changes! (`service apache2 restart`)

Comment: Alright, it worked. Just needed an `service apache2 restart` too. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: where .htacces i can find? Sorry for stupid question, but i can't find :)

Comment: @MilanNz The `.htaccess` can be found in the `public` directory of your application. However the code from this answer goes inside a vhost file. The location of that depends on your server. (e.g. for apache2 and unix it's usually at `/etc/apache2/sites-available`)

Comment: The FollowSymLinks seemed to be key for me.

Comment: Whether we have to add that inside <virtualhost> or outside of it ?

Comment: Run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable mod_rewrite

Comment: Adding this to my vhosts in apache2 gives me error `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
` and the error message inside says it cannot restart apache

Comment: @divHelper11 u probably adding it without the `<Directory>` tag. U have to paste it inside your `<VirtualHost>` Tags (Just like a nested HTML Element).

Comment: It fixed my issue. I use xampp virtual host.

Answer (score 142):

I resolved by doing the following:
Check if there is a module called rewrite.load in your apache at:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

If it does not exist execute the following excerpt:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Otherwise, change the Apache configuration file to consolidate use of the "friendly URL".

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Find the following code inside the editor:

```
<Directory /var/www/> 
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change to:

```
<Directory /var/www/> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that restart the Apache server via:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: I am getting 500 Internal Server Error after that.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me too, in 2019. What does it mean though?

Comment: @chuck The AllowOverride directive specifies, in categories, which guidelines will be accepted if found in an .htaccess file.

Comment: For some reasons, other commands to activate the rewrite didn't work, but this one did. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you soooo much my friend!!! I really appreciate your answer! You helped me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Its worked for me. I used it for my Laravel project.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, June 2020, Fixed the issue, thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Not seems to be fixed on Ubuntu 20.04 AMI (AWS)

Comment: It worked for me in 2022 using Apache and GCP on Debian 9, thanks

Comment: It worked for me in 2023 using ubuntu Apache

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Date: 20230811

Answer (score 30):

First enable `a2enmod rewrite`
next restart the apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

[click  here for answer these question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458080/the-requested-url-projectname-users-was-not-found-on-this-server-laravel)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @rohit i  unable to update the answer  here,click the above link you will find answer

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively you could replace all the contents in your .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

See the docs here.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#web-server-configuration

Answer (score 9):

For Ubunutu 18.04 inside a vagrant box ... This is what helped me

1. Ensure www-data has permissions to the .htaccess file

   ```
     
       sudo chown www-data.www-data .htaccess
   ```
2. edit the apache2 conf to allow for symlinks etc

   ```
     
       sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```

   Add this to the file

```html
<Directory /var/www/html/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3. Restart your apache2 server

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You're answer is also good to resolve this. all we need to do is AllowOverride all

Answer (score 3):

In addition to all the answers if you still encounter some variation of the problem, edit the `.env` file and set `APP_URL` to your domain name as in:

```
 APP_URL=similar_to_my_avatar_link
```

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf file you need to remove #

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

after removing # line will look like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And Apache restart

Answer (score 0):

too late.. but for the benefit
you can edit your .htaccess file 
comment this line

```
  #  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have **mod_rewrite** enabled.

```
restart apache
```

and clear **cookies** of your browser for read again at *.htaccess*

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue on my local machine (Windows 11), after few hours, I found that most of the applications now redirecting to HTTPS, and XAMPP has different configuration for secure virtualhost, after creating secure virtual host similar to non-ssl one, I solved this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem in `cPanel` and I fixed my problem to add in `.htaccess` file below these line

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to .htaccess in public folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

In current version of Apache in httpd.conf there are lines:

```
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
   ...
</Directory>
```

instead of earlier here mentioned:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory /var/www/
   ...
</Directory>
```

It depends on your server's directory structure, but by default I guess it can look like this.

As was recommended, inside Directory tag I changed options like this:

```
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
```

by default it was `AllowOverride none`. It helped.

And of course `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in the same file should be switched on.

Answer (score -1):

For ubuntu!

You need to edit this file: `nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/apache2.conf`

Change this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then just: `sudo systemctl reload apache2`