# Laravel Use HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have project and I installed SSL certificate on ubuntu server. I have done every solution I found but still getting this message every time I open a page.

```
The requested URL /about was not found on this server.
```

Here is what I have changed to force Laravel to use https:

1- I have changed .htaccess in my public folder and added these lines

```
# Added to Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

2- In app->Providers->AppServiceProvider I have add this to boot() function

```
if (App::environment() === 'production' || App::environment() === 'dev') {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
```

3- I have created php artisan make:middleware ForceSSL and added the below code to the handle function

```
 if (!$request->secure() && in_array(env('APP_ENV'), ['stage', 'production'])) {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
```

and in Kernal.php

```
\MyApp\Http\Middleware\ForceSSL::class
```

In .env file I have changed the APP_URL to https://
and I have also changes APP_URL in app.php inside config folder.

What I have missing here? Since two days I couldn't figure out why :(

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242495/laravel-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server) did not help?

Comment: Do you have a route/url `/about` set up in your routes? Maybe redo the config? `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: check route using php artisan route:list

Comment: This may be a silly question but did you setup your vhost to serve https in addition to http ? By default you have `<VirtualHost *:80>` which is only for http and you need to also have a `<VirtualHost *:443>` with certificate configuration

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache? (or something else)

Comment: I fix it using this solution and restart apache
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198007/1789976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things  you need to make sure working :

1. Is your route working in standard HTTP mode without `index.php` in url. Like sometimes laravel.com/aboutus does no work but laravel.com/index.php/aboutus works. If its the case, you need to enable `mod_rewrites` in php and then add `AllowOverride All` in  your virtualhost configurations and restart apache.
2. Coming to HTTPS, what you have setup in laravel will make laravel request forwarded to a secure HTTPS url. However, your server must be able listen, handle and respond to HTTPS request.
3. You need to enable yoru virtualhost to listen to port `443` which is the SSL port. Also, if you have SSL certificates, those need to be configured as well.
4. Before knowing if laravel works on HTTPS, make a simple php file and try to access it using HTTPS of the server url. If that works then you can check whats wrong in laravel. If that does not, then SSL is no configured correctly on your server.
5. Lastly, check `.htaccess` rewrite conditions.
6. `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan route:cache`

Hope this helps to debug this

Comment: I am using apache2

Comment: The home page is opening, all other pages not working.

Comment: If you are saying your homepage works with HTTPS but not the inner pages, check with `.htaccess` file and

Answer (score 0):

AWS  | Centos | EC2 | AWS Certificate

A little bit late, but myself I only had to change this in my env. file :

```
APP_URL=http://localhost

to

APP_URL=https://localhost
```

Everything is working smoothly.