Ajax call is not taking full path without including Project Name
My project is running on an IP where there are other projects too. If I add the full URL in my ajax call then it works fine. Like:-
          $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://192.168.0.10/demo_projects/check_login",
                data: {login_name: login_name},
                
                success : function(res){
                    
                }
            });

If i add only end point path like this:-
          $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: "/check_login",
                data: {login_name: login_name},
                
                success : function(res){
                    
                }
            });

It only takes the IP address and not the project name associated with it. Only IP goes in URL like: http://192.168.0.10/check_login. This URL is the culprit of error.
Is there a way so that I don't have to provide the full path?

What error do you get when you don't enter the IP address in the URL? Is it visible in the browser console?

This error is coming: "The requested URL was not found on this server."

This might solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/28242572/6796856

$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  type: "POST",
  url: "/demo_projects/check_login",
  data: {login_name: login_name},
  success : function(res) {
                    
  }
});

Try this add /demo_projects/check_login in your URL
now it will be hit on http://192.168.0.10/demo_projects/check_login

I know this. My question is that I should not have to add the project name in the URL
