# Laravel 5.2 project - deployment on Linux

Tags: php, git, laravel-5

I am developing an application on Laravel 5.2. I am done with development and deploying the application on a linux server.
I moved the source code using git and executed migrations. I can see everything but when I access the project (any url) it gives 404 error.

```
The requested URL /project_name/public/ROUTE_NAME was not found on this server.
```

I checked apache logs, they say

```
Wed May 25 17:17:15 2016] [error] [client 172.16.17.15] File does not exist: /var/www/html/project_name/public/ROUTE_NAME
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite on the server ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix would like to know about it, let me know what do I need to check. I have been deploying apps developer on other frameworks but this is the first time on laravel.

Comment: what url you hit show your route file

Comment: @Pradeep I have the routes in my routes.php, the same code is working fine on linux. That's something related to re-writing I guess. I didn't modify apache conf

Comment: @VasilShaddix yes I can access it as /public/index.php/ROUTE_NAME but  can't see the layout loaded ... only the form with broken css

Comment: @VasilShaddix can't tag you in the answer down there. I can see in the answer that root directory has been modified.. Do I need to that as well?  i don't want to point the root on this project since I have other projects there

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo what you can do is `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/project_name/public">
Allowoverride All
</Directory>` no need to modify the document root.

Comment: @VasilShaddix Thanks man that worked..I can upvote you if you write your comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem is the missing of the module mod_rewrite on the apache.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

The routing system of laravel works on it. It just takes your url and does it's magic. But without this mode it wont work.

In your index.php in the public folder try

`phpinfo();die();`

To see if you have the mode activated.

If the mode is not active you can follow this instructions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24354757/4969969

without the need to modify the entire document root folder of the server:

`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/" 
....
<Directory "/var/www/html/project_name/public"> 
    Allowoverride All 
</Directory>`

Comment: i checked out phpinfo, i can see mod_rewrite  in Loaded Modules

Comment: can you try running in the browser /public/index.php/ROUTE_NAME ?

Comment: Your problem is the mod_rewrite. You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24354757/4969969 this answer. I think it is well explained.