# Laravel 5.2 routing failed

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

In the file routes.php

when i have  :

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'AdhererController@show']);
```

it works with url http://localhost/adhesion/public/

but when i have

```
Route::get('/adherer', ['uses' => 'AdhererController@show']);
```

or 
    Route::get('adherer', ['uses' => 'AdhererController@show']);

it doesn't works with urls

- http://localhost/adhesion/public/adherer
- http://localhost/adhesion/adherer
- http://localhost/adherer

The error is :

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /adhesion/public/adherer was not found on this
>   server. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

What's wrong ?

Thanks in adavance for any helps !

Comment: try only `adherer` insted of `/adherer`

Comment: same error with adherer ..

Comment: Seems like you misunderstand the sense of routing.

Comment: how you are creating this url ?

Comment: http://localhost/adhesion is created with php artisan but i have created http://localhost/adhesion/public/adherer myself

Answer (score 0):

may be try: http://localhost/adhesion/adherer or http://localhost/adherer
i hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Routing:**

When you have a route like this, `/adherer`

`Route::get('/adherer', ['uses' => 'AdhererController@show']);`

You will access this through this URL

`example.com/adherer` or in your case, `http://localhost/adherer`

**NOT**

**http://localhost/adhesion/public/adherer**

Everything you put in **your route starts from your base url.**

Answer (score 0):

Change your url to this, Remove `public`

```
/adhesion/adherer
```

From

```
/adhesion/public/adherer
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem relative to apache configuration with laravel :

[The requested URL /ProjectName/users was not found on this server. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458080/the-requested-url-projectname-users-was-not-found-on-this-server-laravel/24354757#24354757)

Apache DocumentRoot must point to 'RoadToProjectName/ProjectName/public'

Afer that

```
Route::get ( '/adhesion/adherer', [
        'as' => 'ctrl_adherer',
        'uses' => 'AdhererController@show' 
] );
```

works with url http://localhost/adhesion/adherer

Answer (score 0):

In file: .env, modify APP_URL to:

```
APP_URL=..
```

Try this:

```
Route::get('adherer', 'AdhererController@show');
```

Test: http://localhost/adhesion/public/adherer

By the way, you could create apache config to resolve your issues:

```
Alias /your_project /var/www/html/your_project/public/
<Directory "/var/www/html/your_project/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```