# Laravel Ubuntu 16.04 returning status code 500

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu, xampp, laravel-5.3

I just deployed a Laravel project I developed at localhost (using XAMPP) to a server.

I uploaded all files, created a new .env file (also got an app-key), ran composer install, created the db, ran artisan migrate.

Also, in 
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` I set the DocumentRoot to the public directory of laravel. Also I tried to edit the `apache2.conf` to include the directory, with `Allowoverride All`.

But entering the ip of my server, I get redirect to the login page (of course, I'm using the `Auth` of Laravel).

But I'm getting the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I tried to follow [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458080/the-requested-url-projectname-users-was-not-found-on-this-server-laravel/24354757#24354757) steps, but it's all the same. Except the one point, that in my `apache2.conf` I don't wrote the DocumentRoot anymore, as I already set it in the `000-default.conf`. I also tried to set it a second time in the `apache2.conf`, but this changed nothing.

So what couuld the problem be?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

PS: Something seems to happen inside of laravel. When I go an existing route, I always get this error code 500. When I go to a route, that doesn't exist, I get an error (`NotFoundHttpException`), so the Routing itself kinda seems to work, but where does this error come from? It are exactly the local files I'm using with XAMPP, and locally it works fine... Any ideas?

**EDIT:** After editing my logs directory to have permissions like 777, I'm getting 2 errors as well.

Both point to storage/framework/views/ and storage/framework/sessions, saying "Permission denied". Do I just have to run chmod for those directories as well?

Comment: Yup, you have to change permissions for all `storage` directory recursively.  If you're using 777 then `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/laravel/storage`

Answer (score 1):

Check the error in `storage/logs/laravel.log` if there is no log there then make sure your directory permissions for `storage` allows it to be writeable `775` is what I normally use.

Comment: There seems to be no log generated, when is it generated? I set the folder permission to 775.

Comment: none there is a red flag that permissions could be the issue.  Was the `storage/logs` directory there?  I dealt with a similar issue before that I though was permissions but turned out my storage directory had been removed.  Make sure your storage directory matches the default: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/storage

Comment: yes, there is no `laravel.log` at all, directory structure is fine, the only thing in the `logs` folder is the `gitignore`... Could there something I'm missing in the overall configuration or something? Actually Laravel somehow seems to work (as described), because undefined routes throw this error, whereas existing routes (like the `/login`), return this error code 500...

Comment: EDIT: I tried changing the permissions for logs directory to 777, now the file got generated, as well I'm getting the errors in browser, I'll edit my question to represent those, can you have a look?

Comment: Got it, I'll answer it myself, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it, basically it was the permissions.

I now changed the owner of the `storage` folder to `www-data`. Now it's working (for anyone that might experience this problem, too).

Answer (score 0):

if you use vps ubuntu, you have to set write/read permission with root folder (and all file, folder of it) by using this command on putty:

> chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

i tried this command, and my website doest not show 500 error