# Route Conflict in Laravel 5.3 on amazon server

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

My login route is

```
  Route::post('/user/login', array('as' => 'userlogin', 'uses' => 'UserController@login'));
```

I have debug the code line by line on local server , flow is coming in UserController's **login**  function. It is working perfecly fine on the local server , but as i deployed the source on **amazon** it is throwing an error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
```

I have tried many solutions but nothing worked for me. Any suggestions in this regard ?

Comment: Can you share Local server Url and Amazon server Url??

Comment: Route::post('/user/login', array('as' => 'userlogin', 'uses' => 'UserController@login'));
Route::get('/user/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'UserController@logout'))

URLS  are same some on both side

Comment: i am asking for URL, Not for Route | "http://project-name/public/..."

Comment: 1.2.0/admin/  , on local http://localhost/abc/admin/

Comment: try to add public after abc

Comment: on amazon actually i am  not able to login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140038/discussion-between-user7597883-and-meera-tank).

Comment: Problem is in your .htaccess file, check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458080/the-requested-url-projectname-users-was-not-found-on-this-server-laravel/24354757#24354757](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458080/the-requested-url-projectname-users-was-not-found-on-this-server-laravel/24354757#24354757)